# java.lang.NullPointerException when publish in a ros topic

Tags: java, android, ros

I have got the following exception:

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.ros.android.android_tutorial_pubsub.Talker.publish
```

when I press a button which calls the publish() method showed. It is so weird for me since I have a similar code working perfectly well. I understand the error but I don't see any reason why is produced. Any ideas?

```
class Talker extends AbstractNodeMain {

private Publisher<std_msgs.String> wordPublisher;
private java.lang.String WordTopicName = "chatter";


@Override
public GraphName getDefaultNodeName() {
    return GraphName.of("talker");
}

@Override
public void onStart(final ConnectedNode connectedNode) {
    this.wordPublisher = connectedNode.newPublisher(WordTopicName, std_msgs.String._TYPE);

}

public void publish(java.lang.String str_word) {
    std_msgs.String str = this.wordPublisher.newMessage();
    str.setData(str_word);
    wordPublisher.publish(str);
}
}
```

Comment: may be you need to initialize your `wordPublisher`?

Comment: It is initialized in onStart() function isn't it?